# Filtering a dataframe in r row names from a second data frame in r

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have the data.frame :

```
df1<-data.frame("Sp1"=1:6,"Sp2"=7:12,"Sp3"=13:18)
rownames(df1)=c("A","B","C","D","E","F")

df1

  Sp1 Sp2 Sp3
A   1   7  13
B   2   8  14
C   3   9  15
D   4  10  16
E   5  11  17
F   6  12  18
```

I filter `df1` by a cutoff value for `rowSums(df1)` and return sites (row names) that I want to include in downstream analysis.

```
include<-rownames(df1[rowSums(df1)>=22,])
include

[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

I have a second data.frame :

```
df2<-data.frame(site.x=c("A","B","C"), site.y=c("D","E","F"),score=1:3)

  site.x site.y score
1      A      D     1
2      B      E     2
3      C      F     3
```

I want to filter df2 such that it only includes rows where `df2$site.x` and `df2$site.y` are exactly equal to the sites listed in 'include' i.e. filtering out the row containing "A" and returning.

```
  site.x site.y score    
2      B      E     2
3      C      F     3
```

I have tried :

```
filter<-df2$site.x == include & df2$site.y == include   

filtered<-df2[filter,]
```

Thanks for any advice!

ANSWER

use %in%

```
filter<-df2$site.x %in% include & df2$site.y =%in% include  

filtered<-df2[filter,]
filtered

   site.x site.y score
 2      B      E     2
 3      C      F     3
```

Comment: maybe with `%in%`  instead of `==`

Comment: no dice! Do you think it has something to do with how 'include' is structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it works with :

```
filter<-df2$site.x %in% include & df2$site.y %in% include
df2[filter,]
```

In fact, you've put `df1` instead of `df2` in the last two lines of your question.